# Using Markdown with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, markdown, erb

I want users to type in Markdown text in a textarea and when they post it, I display the corresponding html. I read that Rails used to have a `markdown` method or similarly called method, that you could just call on that field in the ERB file:

```
<%= markdown(@post.content) %>
```

Apparently, Rails took that functionality out. What is the best way to get that functionality again? That seems to solve my need.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would use [Redcarpet](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet) to do the markdown-html conversion. Also, I would move the conversion from the view to some other object. You could use [callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview) (`before_save`) or use [Observers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#observers).

From [the docs](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet#and-its-like-really-simple-to-use):

```
markdown = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(Redcarpet::Render::HTML,
    :autolink => true, :space_after_headers => true)

markdown.render("This is *bongos*, indeed.")
#=> "<p>This is <em>bongos</em>, indeed</p>"
```

You probably want to store the result in another column, say `@post.content_parsed` so that the user can make later edits to the post, plus this way you don't need to make the conversion on every request.

Comment: Where is the best place to instantiate the Redcarpet::Markdown object in a Rails app?

Comment: The Redcarpet github page suggests to only instantiate `Redcarpet::Markdown` once and then call `render` as you need it. Makes sense, but where do I instantiate `Redcarpet::Markdown` only once in my Rails app?

Comment: In that case you can create your own initializer and assign the newly created object to a constant, making it available to the whole application. Although I would never do that - introducing and depending on constants makes things hard to test, especially in isolation.

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution

##### Gemfile

```
gem "redcarpet"
```

##### config/initializers/markdown_renderer.rb

```
module MarkdownRenderer
  def self.markdown
    @@markdown ||=
      Redcarpet::Markdown.new(
        Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new(
          escape_html: true,
          hard_wrap: true,
          safe_links_only: true,
          with_toc_data: true
        ),
        autolink: true,
        fenced_code_blocks: true,
        no_intra_emphasis: true,
        space_after_headers: true,
        tables: true
      )
  end

  def self.render(text)
    markdown.render(text)
  end
end
```

##### app/helpers/application_helper.rb

```
def markdown(text)
  MarkdownRenderer.render(text).html_safe
end
```

##### your view

```
<%= markdown(@post.content) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided had been turned into a gem `emd`. You can read more [here](https://github.com/ytbryan/emd)

Add these lines to your application's Gemfile:

```
gem 'coderay' #optional for Syntax Highlighting
gem 'redcarpet'
gem 'emd'
```

And then execute:

```
bundle
```

To create markdown partial, view or enable syntax highlighting on code block, visit the [usage of emd](https://github.com/ytbryan/emd#usage)